# Problema con ñ en expresión regular

Tags: php

Tengo esta expresión regular en la cual reconoce las url, pero estoy teniendo un error cuando quiero incorporar que el texto reconozca acentos y eñes `ñ`:

```
function findReplaceURL($text){
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
    return preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href=".$url[0]."target='_blank'>".$url[0]."</a>", $text);
    } else {
        return $text;
    }
}
```

Y esto es lo estoy tratando de insertar:

```
[a-zA-Z áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ]
```

Si bien el sitio tiene `<meta charset="utf-8">` y la base guarda los acentos y las eñes `ñ`, cuando lo subo no se ven bien. También traté de usar `utf8_decode($fila['nota'])` pero también se ve mal.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con expresiones regulares de javascript (puedes añadirlas con jquery o en el evento keypress o onBlour).

```
/^[ñA-Za-z _]*[ñA-Za-z][ñA-Za-z _]*$/
```

O intenta así

```
/^[ñA-Za-z _]*[ñA-Za-z][ñA-Za-z _]*$/
```

Comment: Pero tambien tengo que reconocer los acentos, aunque lo puebo y me da un error. Asi fue como lo modifique `$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/^[ñA-Za-z _]*[ñA-Za-z][ñA-Za-z _]*$/";`

Comment: Según lo que entiendo, lo que deseas hacer es que el programa te detecte que NO ingrese caracteres con tildes y/o "ñ" ¿cierto?.

Comment: Claro, la funcion solo reconoce una `url` pero no las enies ni las tildes. Entonces trato de agregar esa expresion regular y no obtengo resultados!